# Is color of icon in a shortcut always black?

Tags: android, shortcut

I am new to app shortcuts in Android. I am using ShortcutInfo.Builder for that.
I also set an icon with the SetIcon function. But the icon is always (at least on Pixel devices) displayed over a white circle, so I have to specify a dark icon for it to be visible. Is this white circle an standard for Android? Could other launchers have a different color? I am afraid of tinting the icon to always dark and then find devices where it has to be light.

In the pixel device I have tested, it doesn't matter if it is Day or Night mode, the circle around the shortcut icon is always white and the icon must be dark if you want it to be seen.

Update:
I testes with a Huawei and shortcuts are transparent.